# why member declaration is not found in this case

Tags: c++, class, declaration, member

I am using eclipse to write c++ codes. When I try to write a header file and corresponding c++ file, it reminds me "member declaration not found" but I have no idea why this would happen since I declare it in my code...Okay, the codes are like:

LoadMedia.h

```
#pragma once 
#include <string>
#include "LuaBridge.h"

class LoadMedia: public LuaParser
{
public:
         LoadMedia();
         virtual ~LoadMedia();

         void loadScript(luabridge::lua_State* L, const std::string& scriptFilename);
};
```

And then, the LoadMedia.cpp

```
#include "LoadMedia.h"
#include "LuaBridge.h"
#include <string>

LoadMedia::LoadMedia(){}
LoadMedia::~LoadMedia(){}

void LoadMedia::loadScript(luabridge::lua_State* L, const std::string& scriptFilename) 
{
  using namespace luabridge;
  if (luaL_dofile(L, scriptFilename.c_str()) != 0) 
    {
    std::cout << "Error, cannot open the script!" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

It reminds me that the loadScript is "member declaration not found"....Any idea why this is so and how should I correct it? Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: What do you mean, "It reminds me"? Are you getting an actual compiler error? If so, post it.

Comment: @pcarter it is a remind from eclipse...

Comment: I can't reproduce this on visual studio.

Comment: Since I can't see the problem, I will guess the problem is inside "LuaBridge.h".  But then there are lots of possibilities, such as opening some scope and failing to close it within that .h file.  (Do the { } match within that .h file?)

Comment: @JSF thanks for your comments. By "that .h file" you mean "LuaBridge.h" ?

Comment: Yes, I did mean LuaBridge.h  I think the cause of the problem is in there (or something else it `#include`s, rather than in the code you posted.  Unmatched { } are just one guess at what such a problem might be.

Comment: @JSF thank you so much for your comments.